# How to transform Menu icon to Arrow icon?

Tags: jquery, css, animation

How can I make a beautifully transform animation Menu icon to Arrow right?

E.g.:

```
<div class="menu">
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
</div>
```

When menu is closed - this is 3 horizontal lines (burger icon), when *.menu.opened* - top and bottom div's transform to arrow right.

How do it on CSS?

Comment: Show your code, what you tried so far.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It is expected that you at least attempt to code this for yourself. Stack Overflow is not a code writing service. I would suggest that you do some additional research, either via Google or by searching SO, make an attempt and. if you still have trouble, come back with **your code** and explain what you have tried and why it did not work.

Comment: Where are the codes? what to do with empty div tags??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is my simple solution for your question

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.menuToggle').on('click', function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('active');
  });
});
```

```css
.menuToggle {
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 40px;
  width: 50px;
  position: fixed;
  left: 25px;
  top: 25px;
}
.menuToggle span {
  display: block;
  height: 0.4rem;
  position: absolute;
  width: 3rem;
  -webkit-transition: margin .5s ease-in-out, width .5s ease-in-out, -webkit-transform .5s ease-in-out;
  transition: margin .5s ease-in-out, width .5s ease-in-out, -webkit-transform .5s ease-in-out;
  transition: margin .5s ease-in-out, width .5s ease-in-out, transform .5s ease-in-out;
  transition: margin .5s ease-in-out, width .5s ease-in-out, transform .5s ease-in-out, -webkit-transform .5s ease-in-out;
}
.menuToggle span:nth-child(2) {
  margin-top: 0.9rem;
}
.menuToggle span:nth-child(3) {
  margin-top: 1.8rem;
}
.menuToggle.active span:nth-child(odd) {
  margin-left: 1.5rem;
  width: 1.5rem;
}
.menuToggle.active span:nth-child(1) {
  margin-top: 0.5rem;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(30deg);
  transform: rotate(30deg);
}
.menuToggle.active span:nth-child(3) {
  margin-top: 1.3rem;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-30deg);
  transform: rotate(-30deg);
}
.menuToggle span {
  background-color: #777;
  border-radius: 5px;
}
.menuToggle.active span {
  background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="menuToggle">
  <span></span>
  <span></span>
  <span></span>
</div>
```

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/olegkukharuk/u0ng6c6k/)